# App displays URL images from other URLs than my own

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I am unable to make the URL public, but I've pasted the full URL into my browser and can confirm the page is right - the image shows in the browser.

But... when I copy that exact URL into a Xamarin.Forms image, set as:

```
<Image 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Aspect="AspectFit">
    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="https://example.com/images/doesntshow.jpg" 
            CacheValidity="3" 
            CachingEnabled="false"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The image simply will not show.

If I substitute the URL:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg" the image shows fine.

NOTE:  There is 0 possibility the URL is incorrect or has an error because... I'm not typing it; I'm copying/pasting it and it's showing just fine in the browser, just not the Xamarin.Forms app.

I've not a clue as to what to look for.  Does anyone else?

Comment: Are your URLs not https?

Comment: Yes, the URLs are HTTPS.  But I've tried both ways, http and https.  Both work inside the browser.  I had to change "mydomain.com" to "example.com" when posting, but it's my own domain on my own server which won't show in the app, just the browser and the server isn't local to me.

Comment: FYI - I have multiple domains on my server.  I even tried putting the simple image on a second domain, exact same path except for domain name - everything works in the browser with that second URL of mine, but not in the app.

Comment: Is it possible to share one of the URLs, because at this point its just guessing really :)

Comment: when you say "in the browser" are you actually using the device's browser, or a desktop browser?

Comment: Sharing the URL would just show an image in your browser and at this point, the URL is private.  Regarding "in the browser", I am using a reg web browser on my desktop computer, Firefox and Chrome.  Where I'm not seeing the image from my URL only is on the view page within the emulator whilst running my Xamarin.Forms app.  Again though, if I substitute another URL into the same app, it shows fine.  Could there be something on my server which would 1) serve images to a reg desktop browser, but then 2) block them for the app?

Comment: INFO UPDATE:  so I just tried a third domain of mine, on the same server as the other two.  This third one, we'll call DN3, has no SSL on it.  Guess what - the image came through just fine in both desktop browser AND in the Xamarin app under "http".  Even though I had tested just "http" on the other two domains, those still have a secure certificate set in IIS.  My certificates are from Comodo and are up-to-date, installed properly as far as I know as they serve secure content on my websites and other apps (CGI).  So what could cause this then?

Comment: I've discovered something and need to share.  I have URL rewrites on my DN1 and DN2 which rid the "www" and force SSL (https).  When I disable the rules, and access the URL with "http" from the Xamarin app, the images show!  On DN3, there are no URL rewrite rules and no SSL and hence it worked originally.  So... I still need input as I want the images and everything to come across the wire secure (SSL).  I'm on Windows server 2016.  How can I address allowing the Xamarin app to access images securely and keep my (or similar) URL rewrites to force SSL and rid the "www"?

Comment: I've disabled the rewrite rules (both of them), but still can only see the images if I use "http".  Using "https" on images from MY domain doesn't work.  Using "https" on images from another server works.  I do not have the "require SSL" checked in IIS.  Other than this and the rewrite rules, what setting might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE RESOLVED - thanks for the good mental vibes :)

I found the resolution here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105036/images-from-url-not-showing-on-android

April 5

```
"Just change the following options and it should work with https too.
Android Options => Advanced
HttpClient implementation = Set to "Managed" option value
SSL/TLS implementation = set to "Native TLS 1.2+" option value"
```

I still don't understand why prior to this setting change, I could load https images from other servers just fine (e.g. "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg"). So... I will lose a bit of sleep wondering what is different on my server from wiki's. If you have a clue, please share.